# Impossible to set card dates

Tags: trello

Problem: since yesterday I've got problems with setting/changing card dates. Although I'm able to set the date in the calendar on the card, the date doesn't appear on the card.
Saving with green button, doesn't work, saving with enter-tab does work.

After deleting the calendar modus in another board, date-changing worked for a while, but now I'm having the same problem again.

(Maybe it has something to do with the setting of the calendar view, because changing to calendar view sometimes makes the screen freeze with a gray filter.)

(I’m using Safari on OS X 10.6.8, if it matters.)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that's related to https://trello.com/c/qLXbGyYQ/1476-can-t-change-due-dates-in-non-us-mode; which is a recent bug that's been fixed.

[image]